# Web Request Response From Nike.com Forbidden

Tags: c#, web-crawler, webrequest

All I'm trying to do is create a program that gets a web response from Nike's upcoming shoe's page, however I keep running into an error saying this is forbidden. No other threads on this topic have been of use to me, is there anything I can do for this or am I just screwed? This is the code:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.nike.com/launch/?s=upcoming");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

and this is the error:

```
System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a header issue, try this:

```
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application / zip, application / octet - stream");
    client.Headers.Add("Referer", "http://whatevs");
    client.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    String someStuff = client.DownloadString("https://www.hassanhabib.com");
    Console.WriteLine(someStuff);
    Console.Read();
```

Removed the Accept-Encoding line, should be fine now.

Comment: This fixed the forbidden error, however all it returns is gibberish like: ‹??????ì½[säJšö¾¿]÷©b]Éb±‹=l’ÝÍ9¼-É>gæô0( «

Comment: Comment out `client.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");` @BenCompSci. What you are seeing is compressed content.

Comment: I should warn you though, that using this code with a platform that explicitly prohibits using automated scripts might get you in some trouble of violation of terms of use.
Read the terms of use here:
http://agreementservice.svs.nike.com/us/en_us/rest/agreement?agreementType=termsOfUse&uxId=com.nike.commerce.nikedotcom.web&country=US&language=en&requestType=redirect&ref=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F